# Laravel string replace item

Tags: php, laravel

How to i replace '[' charachter to span class = "someclass" .I wrote this code but it gives me only text

```
$replaced = str_replace(
            array('[', ']'),
            array("<span class"."='innovation_color innovation_color-services".">","</"."span".">"),
             $string
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing some quotes :

```
$replaced = str_replace(
            ['[', ']'],
           ["<span class"."='innovation_color innovation_color-services'".">","</"."span".">",
             $string
        );
```